# Saga Orchestration Scability Issue in Microservice Architecture

Tags: c#, microservices, saga

I need to handle distributed transactions in a microservice architecture. In theory, one of the best ways of doing that is using the Saga Orchestration pattern. The problem is I could not find any detailed information about how to provide scalability.

Let's use the example below. There can be many CreateOrderSaga, if I have multiple OrderService.API and it will be the case. Because I can have more than one OrderService.API. Then if CreateOrderSaga is kind of a state machine, then does it mean it should handle all the steps in it by itself or other coordinators can take its job?

Then what if that one API crashes while running the saga process, can other saga coordinators continue to run with the same state where the crashed API left? What's the best way of handling this situation? How an event storing can help ?

**Let me explain in detail**

1. Coordinator1 in one of the Order.APIs, starts the CreateOrderSaga
2. CreateOrderSaga in Coordinator1 creates an order which has
   pending state
3. Then Coordinator1 crashed for some reason. (maybe electricity is gone) the order stayed as pending state and no one is interested now. Someone should continue to process it or should mark it as failed (who has the responsibility) Maybe some compensation transactions are needed also.

So is it ok to make a saga coordinator starts a process but others can also continue to process it?

**How a saga coordinator can be scaled up?**

[image]

[image: c]

**Solution:**

I did choose Masstransit to manage distributed transactions

Comment: Have you looked into service meshes at all?

Comment: @JoshWilliard I am not sure service mesh provides distributed transaction.

Comment: End-to-end tracing of distributed transactions is one of the many upsides to a service mesh deployment

Comment: Are you talking about concurrency in case of failure? How are you handling concurrency? Have you tried actor programming model? Service Fabric/Akka.Net/Orleans

Comment: https://particular.net/blog/you-dont-need-ordered-delivery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saga pattern should be implemented as asynchronous process. In this case `asynchronous` means messaged based. Most types of message queues have acknowledgement feature (for [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)). Here I'm going to describe stateless services (i.e. it's OK to handle `CreateOrder` requests in different instances of `OrderService`).

You click "make an order" button, `CreateOrder` message is sent into message queue, `OrderService` receives this messages from the queue. It's scaled because you can create many instances of `OrderService`.

Then we have two cases:

`1.` **Orchestration-based saga**: `OrderService` receives a message, instantiates coordinator, coordinator consumes `CustomerService`. If `OrderService` fails before completion of message processing, `CreateMessage` message won't be acknowledged in message queue. Subseequently, another instance of `OrderService` will receive the message and try to process it. If `CustomerService` fails during the call: you can fail the entire `CreateOrder` message and retry it later or retry the particular call to `CustomerService`.

`2.` **Choreography-based saga**: `OrderService` receives a message and tries to process the message. If it fails then situation is the same: the message won't be acknowledged and will be redelivered for the next retry later. This approach is about emitting events like `OrderCreated`, `CustomerCreated` etc. (i.e. it's event-oriented)

Of course you should configure monitoring and alerting for your services to be sure that system is alive and able to process messages.

Also you should consider whether you need to implement some compensation logic or checks. Imagine: you make two HTTP POST requests to different services while processing a message, 1st service call is completed successfully but 2nd one fails. If you retry entire `CreateOrder` message - you should not call the 1st service again.

Further reading: [overview of sagas](https://chrisrichardson.net/post/antipatterns/2019/07/09/developing-sagas-part-1.html), [coordinating sagas](https://chrisrichardson.net/post/sagas/2019/08/04/developing-sagas-part-2.html), [choreography-based sagas](https://chrisrichardson.net/post/sagas/2019/08/15/developing-sagas-part-3.html):

> In order for the communication to be reliable, it’s essential that the
>   saga participants use a message broker that guarantees at-least-once
>   delivery and has durable subscriptions. That’s because at-least-once
>   delivery and durable subscriptions ensure that a saga completes even
>   if a participant is temporarily unavailable. A message will sit in the
>   message broker’s channel (e.g. queue or topic) until the participant
>   is able to successfully process it.

To get more thoughts how to implement it properly read how [NServiceBus sagas framework](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/concurrency) is implemented. It's .NET framework for sagas but concepts are language agnostic.

Comment: How communication takes place in Choreography-based. UI -> OrderService -> CustomerService ?

Comment: @PraveenRaghuvanshi message queue producer-consumer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

Comment: Just trying to understand the difference between two approaches mentioned by you. Both of them works on message queuing. Where is the difference?

Comment: @PraveenRaghuvanshi in case of Orchestration initial message and all events are sent into queue. In case of Choreography only initial message is sent into queue.

Comment: @PraveenRaghuvanshi Actually it's possible to use MQ in coordinator case too. The main difference is having one place to coordinate saga flow. In case of choreography services just emit events and other services listen.

Comment: Can we say https://particular.net/blog/you-dont-need-ordered-delivery is an example of Orchestration-based saga and Choreography-based is event driven(includes events for failures as well) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203482/discussion-between-praveen-raghuvanshi-and-mtkachenko).

Comment: I understand the idea but the problem is generally examples are shown as Orchestration is kind of a state-machine. But you say each event message can be taken from message-queue, and it can be proceeded by one of the coordinators. But if I do that, then it will be hard to compensate if any errors occur because the state machine can be run any one of the coordinators. Then the state machine can be started with one of the states because a kindly new coordinator can handle the next event. Now it became harder to maintain if the starting coordinator isn't the one which ends the state-machine.

Comment: @BarışVelioğlu Coordinator is ephemeral. It could be instantiated on any server. Yes, it's not easy to implement it correctly. You should keep saga state somewhere. It gives you ability to restore coordinator in a valid state. About compensation: in distributed systems you should think about compensation anyway. To get more thoughts how to implement it properly read this https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/concurrency . It's .NET framework for sagas but concepts are language agnostic.